# Какую схему при организации исходников лучше всего использовать?

Tags: c++

Мой вопрос касается темы организации C++ исходников.
Ниже указаны два способа: привычный и альтернативный. Я в своих "хобби"-проектах использую второй способ.
Хочу услышать мнение бывалых стоит ли его применять или нет и почему?

1. Привычный

Набор исходных кодов делится на два множества : заголовочные файлы и файлы с реализациями. То есть всем привычные `*.hpp` и `*.cpp`, `*.cc` файлы. Файлы реализации "инклудят" в себя заголовочные файлы. Каждый файл с реализацией в результате дает `*.obj`, которые в последствии используются компоновщиком для получения исполняемого файла.

При использовании этого способа очень часто заголовочный файл находится рядом с файлом реализации. Примеры:
SuperFactory.hpp и рядом лежит в этой же папке SuperFactory.cpp

2. Альтернативный

Этот способ отличается от выше стоящего тем, что вместо большого количества файлов реализаций создается один файл реализации `implementation.cpp`. Да, один cpp-файл. Сделать это можно так: файлы `*.cpp`, `*.cc` становятся заголовочными файлами содержащими реализации и "инклудяющиеся" в `implementation.cpp`.

В этом способе заголовочные файлы содержащие объявления лежат в отдельной папке, к примеру `include`. А заголовочные файлы содержащие реализацию в другой `implementation`. Схематически можно представить так:

```
include\
...proba1.hpp
...proba2.hpp

implementation\
...proba1.hpp
...proba2.hpp

include.hpp:
#include <include/proba1.hpp>
#include <include/proba2.hpp>

implementation.hpp:
#include <implementation/proba1.hpp>
#include <implementation/proba2.hpp>

implementation.cpp:
#include <precompiled_headers.hpp>
#include <include.hpp>
#include <implementation.hpp>
```

Как уже говорил выше я использую второй способ в своих "хобби" проектах. Мне хочется понять, что по мимо "непривычности" может служить причиной отказаться от использования второго способа и почему?

Comment: Как минимум - в результате все зависит от всего, и на любой чих нужна полная перекомпиляция - не нравится мне это...

Comment: @Harry: Извините, но не пойму. Почему полная перекомпиляция. По второму все тоже самое, только в одном cpp файле. Прошу проследить по-внимательнее и если имеет место быть, то прошу дать более развернутый вопрос. Уверен у вас богатый опыт, так что не жмотьтесь и делитесь ;)

Comment: Ну правильно - все в одном файле. Весь исходный код. И компилируется при любом внесении исправлений в самый мелкий .cpp, в котором ничего и нет, все, что есть во всей программе. Или я что-то не так понимаю?... И, кстати, разнесение по отдельным файлам несколько дисциплинирует, что ли... Поневоле начинаешь думать о том, как зависимостей поменьше получить, глобальные переменные и т.п. не использовать - а тут ну прямо приглашение какое-то: все видят всё.

Comment: 1. Про компиляцию теперь понятно. Согласен. 2. По разнесение по отдельным файлам: во втором способе точно также как и в первом. Было Proba1.hpp и Proba1.cpp , а стало include/Proba1.hpp и implementation/Proba1.hpp .

Comment: Ну я же не сказал, что такой способ **заставляет**, он скорее *провоцирует* :)

Comment: Если стремиться к монолиту и не прочь попить чайку, изменив пару строк в исходнике, то второй способ вполне годится. Если же держать в голове повторное использование .o/.h, то определенно нет.

Comment: @avp: Почему ВЫ так не любите писать ответы? Опыт же у вас есть и им нужно делиться! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Т.к., по сути, у вас получается, во втором случае, одна единица трансляции, то изменение любой части приводит к полной её пересборке.

Отсюда минусы:

1. на больших проектах сборка дольше. И она будет всё замедляться по мере роста проекта.
2. в случае C++ при такой организации, вполне себе можно получить ситуацию, когда компилятору не хватит памяти. Особенно если будут шаблоны, особенно рекурсивные.
3. может нарушиться инкапсуляция уровня единицы трансляции (статические переменные, анонимные пространства имён становятся доступны всем, без контроля).

В случае отдельных `.cpp` файлов, каждый транслируется в свой `.o` файл, а потом линковщиком собираются в один исполняемый. Как результат: если поменялся только один из файлов-реализации, то пересобирается только его `.o` файл и потом линковщик пересобирает их со старыми.

Это не спасёт, правда, если изменения делались в `.h` файлах и он много где подключается: будут пересобраны все `.cpp` файлы, в которых он используется (тут очень много зависит от построения зависимостей системой конфигурации/билда). Это, кстати, повод не создавать супер-заголовочников, которые подключают половину вашей системы, а так же стараться использовать по минимум `#include` в заголовочных файлах вообще. Случай с precompiler headers не рассматриваю.

Ну и когда заголовочный файл и файл-реализации лежат в разных директориях, то не совсем удобно обходить проект при помощи файлового менеджера: не обязательно же грузить IDE, что бы бегло посмотреть проект.